# Openfire - Broadcast message to all multi user chatrooms in a conference service

Tags: chat, broadcast, openfire

Using OpenFire 3.71, I have a couple of different conference services, each has a couple of chat rooms in it.

Now I want to broadcast messages to all the MUC ROOMS within one of the services and not as "private messages" to the individual users in those rooms/services. (It should more or less look like as if I entered every single room, sent a message, and left...)

Is that possible in some way? Is there a plugin already? Or is at least possible to write such an plugin? I'm not really sure how the MUC's work...If somebody knows a good source for that, that would be nice to read too...

Thanks,
Jens

Comment: I heard of the mucho plugin (http://josjos.se/blog/projekt/mucho/) which seems to make this a little easier, but I was hoping for a nicer solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround, in case anybody needs something similar:

I implemented the clients now in the way that they will automatically join a default (per service) muc in addition to the room they join manually. In this default room, only the "owner" can send messages and once the client receives a message in this chat it is displayed within the room that s/he is "actually" in...

As usual for "workarounds" it's surely not the best solution, but it works for my purpose...

If you know of a better solution please let me know.